# Encountering permissions issue when trying to install TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to install TensorFlow and I'm getting this error.

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\~ompiler\\tf2tensorrt\\_pywrap_py_utils.pyd'
Check the permissions.
```

I tried to install with this: `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow --user`

I Googled for a solution. I haven't found anything yet. Has anyone encountered this? Better yet, any solutions for this kind of thing?

Comment: are you the admin?, are you using windows defender?

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing it, don't use the upgrade flag, try `pip install tensorflow` instead or `pip install tensorflow --user` or `pip3 install tensorflow` or `python3 -m pip install tensorflow`.

Also check if windows defender is blocking the installation. You can check the shield icon in the bottom left corner in the notification area.

If you don't give it permission, it will not allow you to modify any system files.

You also need to have permission to read and write files / data in your account. Please make sure you have administrator rights in your account.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that if you're trying to do this from a virtual environment, you should just run your terminal as Administrator. So for example, I ran into this issue trying to install in a virtual environment from a Powershell terminal in VSCode, so I just had to close VSCode, and restart it as administrator for it to work.